# Most elegant way to parse xml data and handle custom array element values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xmlserializer

What would be the best way to parse xml such as:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
      <shapeTemplate>
          <vertex_contours>
              <vertex_contour>
                  <data>1 2 3 4 5 ... </data>
              </vertex_contour>
              ...
          </vertex_contours>

      </shapeTemplate>
```

My instincts tell me that I should be using C# deserialization and use XmlSerializer e.g. :

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("shapeTemplate")]
public class ShapeTemplate
{
    [XmlArray("vertex_contours")]
    [XmlArrayItem("vertex_contour", typeof(VertexContour))]
    public VertexContour[] VertexContours { get; set; }
}
```

But then I realized XmlSerializer could not just parse and convert <data> into IEnumerable<int>

So I was wondering what the suggested approach is to handling such a situation. Initially I was using XElement.Parse(...) but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution than that.

Comment: Whilst it is true that `XmlSerializer` can´t serialize/deserialize from/into `IEnumerable<T>` you can implement `IXmlSerializable`-interface self and read/write your data. See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly for further details.

Comment: Indeed IXmlSerializable does what I am looking for, the only question now is whether this approach is better or worse than using Linq to Xml...

Comment: Getting the array items is complicated because you don't have Tag for each item in the XML. Therefore you need to parse it by your own. Can you add Tag for each item?

Comment: No since in reality the array has 1000's of values

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string values = (string)doc.Descendants("data").FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was doing initially but I didn't like that I needed to instantiate and initialize the relevant classes myself. I thought I could use XmlSerializer to do most of this work for me...

Comment: You didn't specify what tags you needed.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the question? I stated I already had a linq to xml solution...

Comment: Yes it does.  You didn't say you had a linq solution. You asked for a more elegant solution than serialization and I provided it to you.